# Can't make a remote character smooth using interpolation

Tags: javascript, math, interpolation, game-development, impactjs

I am developing an online shooter game using Impact.js, Node.js and WebSocket for communication. I am facing an issue with smooth movement of enemy character whose data is received from the server via WebSocket.

And the question is what do I need to fix to make moving a character stop being laggy?

How character movement is sent to the server in the **update** function, which calls 60 times per second (by frame count):

```
update: function() {
  ...
  this.packageNum += 1
  this.connection.emit('movement', {
            time: Date.now(),
            flip: this.flip,
            velY: (this.pos.y - this.last.y) ,
            velX: (this.pos.x - this.last.x) ,
            frame: this.currentAnim.frame,
            animName: animName,
            x: this.pos.x,
            y: this.pos.y,
            time: Date.now(),
            packageNum: this.packageNum
  })
}
```

How data is received on the server and sent to other players:

```
async function onMovement(data) {
  try {
    if (room && room.sockets) {
      Object.entries(room.sockets).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        socket.to(value.id).emit(MessageType.MOVEMENT, data)
      })
    }
  } catch (error) {}
}
```

Receiving data from the server, we set state for this remote player:

```
setState: function(state) {
  if (this.lastPackageNum < state.positionData.packageNum) {
    this.lastPackageNum = state.positionData.packageNum
    this.RcvNewLocation({x: state.positionData.x, y: state.positionData.y});
    if (state.positionData.flip) {
      this.offset.x = 29
    } else {
      this.offset.x = 70
    }
    this.currentAnim = this.anims[`${state.positionData.animName}`]
    this.currentAnim.frame = state.positionData.frame;
    this.currentAnim.flip.x = !!state.positionData.flip;
  }
},

RcvNewLocation: function(rcvedLocation) {
      this.locationCurrent = this.locationNew;
      this.locationNew = rcvedLocation;
},
```

In the **update** function (which again is called 60 times per second) we update the position using interpolation:

```
update: function() {
  if (this.stateUpdated) {
    this.stateUpdated = false;
  } else {
    this.UpdateLocation();
    this.pos.x = this.locationCurrent.x;
    this.pos.y = this.locationCurrent.y;
    if (this.currentAnim) {
      this.currentAnim.update();
    }
  }
},

UpdateLocation: function() {
  this.locationCurrent = this.LerpVec2(this.locationCurrent, this.locationNew);
},

LerpVec2: function(from, to) {
    return {
        x: from.x * (1 - ig.system.tick) + to.x * ig.system.tick,
        y: from.y * (1 - ig.system.tick) + to.y * ig.system.tick
    };
},
```

Comment: Many online  games do not update over a socket 60 times per second, because it can be laggy / unpredictable. Instead you just update once or twice per second, and use motion tweening to make the character move smoothly from the old position to the new updated position. You can also keep track of how much time is between updates to make sure the movement stays smooth.